# Who is this Devi?

Tags: identification-request, goddess

[image]

Who is this Devi holding parrot in one hand? Kindly provide the authentic dhyana sloka.

Comment: She sits like Dakshinamurthy with same Chin Mudra, Japamala, Vedas. Generally Kanchi Kamakshi and Madura Meenakshi  forms have Parrots.

Comment: @TheDestroyer there is some name and dhyana of this form i hope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

She is [Sri Saradamba](https://www.sringeri.net/temples/sri-sharadamba) of Sringeri.

[image]

[Dhyana Sloka](http://svbf.org/newsletters/year-2012/the-jagadguru-speaks/) of Saradamba: (which resembles Dhyana Sloka of Dakshinamurthy as Saradamba is feminine form of Dakshinamurthy)

> मुद्रामक्षगुणं सुधाढ्यकलशं विद्यां च हस्तांबुजैर्बिभ्राणाम्।
>
> mudrāmakṣaguṇaṃ sudhāḍhyakalaśaṃ vidyāṃ ca hastāṃbujairbibhrāṇām।

Comment: This Dhyana-sloka accirding to Tantra is of VAgdevi and VAhya-matrika. There is no mention of the bird

Comment: And the Dhyana-sloka mentions Her as 'Trinayana' but here She has only two eyes!

Comment: @Pratimaputra there might be another Dhyana Sloka. Even i don't know Dakshinamurthy form with Parrot, although there are 16 forms of Dakshinamurthy.

Comment: All four hands except parrot and eyes identical.So these two i think are local alterations

Comment: @Pratimaputra Looks like this is Dhyana sloka of VagDevata. http://aupasana.com/blog/2016/03/matrika.html

Comment: yes, I already mentioned.Its of VAgdevi/VAgdevatA dhyana and VAhya-mAtrika given in TantrasAra and to be chanted before Anga-nyAsa of any puja