# Significance of Parrot, Khadga etc in the hands of Matangi

Tags: sri-vidya, matangi

Whats the significance of Parrot, Khadga and Veena and naarakapaala in the hands of  Ucchista ChandAli MAtangi.

Who is the Upasakar of this devi ?whether these people ONLY chant dhyanams of Goddess Matangi Devi ?

OR

is it mandatory that, we need to go for sreevidya upasana to reach the stage of performing upasana of Matangi, only after Kaali,Tara,Bhuvaneswari,Shodashi etc .. in order to reach this 9th Goddess.
in one of the mantras of HER,its given "namo bhagavati... chandali" and i read somewhere in web that, as "namo bhagavati... chandali**NI**"
which one is correct ?

Comment: Realated Question-https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34127/who-is-this-devi

Comment: No,  i dont think thats similar question. I asked abt Matangi devi not sharada